# Socket Broadcast with UDP Protocol for service discovery performance consideration

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, service-discovery

I'm building a small microservice which does one particular job and needs to be HA. I'm thinking about the implementation of a socket based service discovery. So i can have an other istance of the same service as a hot standby. They talk to each other in order to be synchronised. Yes i could use Redis or any other DB to have them in sync. For this particular service i do not want to be dependent on other services. I came up with this solution which works exactly how i want it. But i'm not sure about the risks of this code from a performance/stability perspective. I'm currently not concerned about security.

```
import socket
import time
import uuid
import struct

instance_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
payload = "this is data"
multicast_group = ('224.31.5.85', 19845)

discovery = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
ttl = struct.pack('b', 1)
discovery.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
discovery.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
discovery.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
discovery.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group[0])
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
discovery.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

discovery.settimeout(0.2)
discovery.bind(("", 19845))
while True:
    message = "/".join([instance_id, payload]).encode()

    # send discovery message
    discovery.sendto(message, multicast_group)

    # process all other received messages
    while True:
            try:
                data, addr = discovery.recvfrom(1024)               
            except socket.timeout:
                break
            else:
                rec_instance_id, rec_payload = data.decode().split("/")
                if not rec_instance_id == instance_id:
                    print("received message: {} from {}".format(data, addr))

    time.sleep(1)
```

What do you think?
The Microservice runs at the end in an Kubernetes Cluster as a Daemonset where other microservices are running as well.

Comment: Are all the nodes communicating with this broadcast discovery protocol on the same LAN segment?   You should account for the possibility of more than 2 nodes broadcasting. As you have it your, loop does a sendto a single recvfrom in the same loop. You might want to account for multiple recvs - especially since you have to filter our your own packets.

Comment: By the way, I built something like this as a prototype a few years back. For a scenario where different nodes of the same app can find each other on the same LAN.

Comment: One broadcast packet per node per second shouldn't cause any performance issues, unless you are planning to have a large number of nodes (e.g. 50+) running at once.

Comment: @selbie all the nodes are in the same segment yes.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner there will be a maximum of 3-4 instances running

Comment: @selbie i've just updated my code to support your input.

Comment: You are misusing broadcast. Many companies now reject applications that broadcast because they are a security risk, waste resources, and interrupt every host on the LAN. We have multicast that will target only those hosts listening to the particular multicast group, and this is the method you should use. In fact, IPv6 has eliminated broadcast, and it makes heavy use of multicast.

Comment: @RonMaupin can you give some details on the nature of the security risk?

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the hint regarding broadcast vs. multicast. It makes totally sense. I've refactored my code to multicast and edited the post here.

Comment: The multicast address you have is RESERVED. You should probably pick one from the Organization-Local Scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). See the IANA maintained _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)_ for more information. You9 can have the server subscribe to the multicast group, the client send a query to the multicast group, then the server can respond with a unicast with its IPv4 address.

Comment: @RonMaupin got it, thanks! Will check that